# Select distinct and count number of rows

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with this structure

```
+----------+----------+
| user_id  | tema_id  |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |    1     |
|        2 |    1     |
|        3 |    2     |
|        4 |    3     |
|        5 |    2     |
|        6 |    3     |
|        7 |    1     |
+----------+----------+
```

What I want to get in only one query is the total of different `tema_id` by `tema_id`. I have this query but it returns the different `tema_id` but the count column to one instead of the total of that `tema_id`.

```
SELECT tema_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(tema_id)) as total
FROM push_subscriptions
GROUP BY tema_id
```

Return this:

```
+----------+----------+
| tema_id  | total    |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |    1     | -> must be 3
|        2 |    1     | -> must be 2
|        3 |    1     | -> must be 2
+----------+----------+
```

Thank you

Comment: Replace `COUNT(DISTINCT(tema_id))` to `COUNT(tema_id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `count(*)` should do the trick:

```
select tema_id, count(*) as total
from push_subscriptions
group by tema_id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cf9d8ce524e321fac42f1ffe1c2c684)